# print single key+value within a list, nested within a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following:

```
device = {
    'BPCM' : ['phone', 'Description: Compact', 'price', 29.99],
    'BPSH' : ['phone', 'Description: Clam Shell', 'price', 49.99],
    'RTMS' : ['Tablet', 'Description: RoboTab - 10-inch screen and 64GB memory', 'price', 299.99],
    'RTLM' : ['Tablet', 'Description: RoboTab - 10-inch screen and 256 GB memory', 'price', 499.99],
} 

print("Hello customer, here is your list of phone and tablet choices. Please choose a phone or tablet by entering your name and the item code:")  
for key, value in device.items():
    print("\nItem Code: " + key)
    print(" " + str(value)) 
name = raw_input("\nPlease tell me your name? ") 
print("Hello " + name)
response = raw_input("Please enter item code: ") 
if response in device.keys():
    print("Item Code Chosen " + response + str(value))
else: 
    print("This code " + response + " is not in our list, please try again or choose quit 'q'")
```

This line: "print("Item Code Chosen " + response + str(value))" appears to be causing problems in that it prints the following output:

```
Item Code Chosen BPCM['phone', 'Description: Clam Shell', 'price', 49.99]
```

The value being printed above is the 2nd value in the dictionary, related to key: RTLM but I expect the 1st value as below:

```
'BPCM'['phone', 'Description: Compact', 'price', 29.99]
```

I cannot see my error?

Comment: You must first get this value from the dictionary before you can print it.

Comment: `value` is always the last value in your dict, as a leftover from your `for` loop. Use `device[response]` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change `str(value)` as below:

```
if response in device.keys():
    print("Item Code Chosen " + response + str(device[response]))
```

Comment: Thank you @Meha - this worked but can you explain the logic? It seems to have cast the whole dictionary and key as a string? i'm struggling to see how that singles out the value for that key? thanks in advance

Comment: yes, you can access values of dictionary using key. Here is doc link: `https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries`

Comment: Always. Happy coding :) you can learn more about python from the doc link I provided in the previous comment.